# Ruby 1.9.3 Creating New Users/Passwords and re-prompting if already in DB?

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm a beginner working with some basic lessons.

Trying to create a new user and if that user is already in the hash, prompt the user again, but once the user is nil, ask for a password, then add to the hash. I have had many attempts. This is just one of them.

```
users = {
    user_1: 2
}


puts "Create New User: Type your username"
new_user = gets.chomp

if users[new_user.to_sym].nil?
  puts "Type in a Password"
  pass = gets.chomp
  users[new_user.to_sym] = pass.to_i

elsif users[new_user.to_sym] != nil
  puts "We already have that user."
  loop do
    if users[new_user.to_sym] != nil
      puts "Try Again"
      ta = gets.chomp
    break if users[ta.to_sym] == nil
   end
  end
end
```

I have tried using `"when, then", "if/else"`, `"until"`, `"while"`, etc (these are the basic functions I know, or at least am learning, and would like to solve using some variation of these if possible), but each time I can't seem to figure out how to apply the username that stops the loop (by finally being nil), back into my primary goal, of adding a new user/password to the hash.

Comment: Do you need to create just one user? Or many?

Comment: I would need the facility for many, though just one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main struggle, I think, is how to go back to setting password after you managed to get a valid name from user. You can extract this code into a method and just call it.

```
users = {
  "user_1" => 2
}


def get_username
  puts "Create New User: Type your username"
  new_user = gets.chomp
end

def get_password users, name
  puts "Type in a Password"
  pass = gets.chomp
  users[name] = pass.to_i
end  

new_user = get_username

if users[new_user].nil?
  get_password users, new_user
else
  puts "We already have that user."

  # ruby's do-while loop. Or, rather, do-while-not in this case :)
  begin
    new_user = get_username
  end unless users[new_user].nil?

  get_password users, new_user
end
```

I also changed the code to use strings as keys (instead of symbols). You should avoid using symbols like that. It has serious consequences (symbols are not garbage-collectable, so you may leak memory if you create too many symbols).

Answer (score 0):

Creating single user:

```
users = {
      user_1: 2
}


check=true
puts "Create New User: Type your username"
new_user = gets.chomp

while(check) do
  if users[new_user.to_sym] != nil
    puts "We already have that user."
    if users[new_user.to_sym] != nil
      puts "Try Again"
      puts "Enter username"
      new_user = gets.chomp
    end
  elsif users[new_user.to_sym].nil?
    puts "Type in a Password"
    pass = gets.chomp
    users[new_user.to_sym] = pass.to_i
    break
  end

end
```